# Can I deploy Php/Drupal application on Jetty or WAS 7?

Tags: php, websphere, jetty

Can I deploy Php/Drupal application on Jetty or WAS 7? Will there be any challenges in not using wamp server and then Jetty?

Thanks

Comment: I think this belongs on Serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

Jetty and Websphere are designed to host Java applications and be general HTTP servers.  They don't seem designed to serve PHP applications.

While some basic web searching seems to indicate that [Jetty can call PHP as a CGI program](http://www.owengriffin.com/posts/2010/04/22/Writing_PHP_applications_with_Maven_and_Jetty.html) (uh, maybe, that's what the blog post that linked there said -- looks more like it's a bunch of XML configuration to me.. Java isn't my thing) and at least an old version of Websphere [has a few other options](http://krook.net/archives/160), you're probably in for a world of pain if you go down this route.

Consider instead using a standard web server as a *reverse proxy* to your Java application server of choice.  Both nginx and Apache can be configured to pass requests on to other servers depending on various conditions, like path pattern matching and being otherwise unable to serve the request.

Comment: Agree that using the front Web Server's PHP capabilities could be the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for WebSphere is the free [Feature Pack for Dynamic Scripting](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/was/featurepacks/dynamicscripting/#), which provides PHP support. I have no idea how the PHP support works, though; for instance whether you could just drop in a Drupal installation under it.

Answer (score 0):

[Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/) is implementation of PHP for JVM. It will possibly work on any servlet container.

PHP with its built-in standard library (written in C) is very quirky and it's very hard to make another implementation of PHP that will be 100% compatible. So some applications may not work in Quercus.

Answer (score 0):

I also need to load PHP page on **WAS V8.5** as front-end of Java Application, here are my findings:

You can use **Dynamic Scripting** to add PHP support OR may these articles can help you:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-read/#in2
http://krook.net/php-ihs-websphere-db2